# Pausing alternate css animation and going back to its origin

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

```js
jQuery( ".button" ).click(function() {

  // STOP BOUNCING SMOOTHLYY
 $('.button').on('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration', function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.removeClass('loading');
 })

});
```

```css
.button{
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(50vh - 10px);
 left: calc(50vw - 10px);

 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;

 border-radius: 100%;
 background-color: green;

 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.loading{
 animation: bouncing 1s ease infinite alternate;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes bouncing{
 from {transform: translateY(0);}
 to {transform: translateY(-100px);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button loading"></div>
```

A bouncing ball animated with css alternate animation (transform: translateY). I want the ball to stop its movement when clicked and go back to its intial place (possibly with smooth easing).

Css doesn't seem to know where the animation is, then it is not able to move back to its original point. Do you have a different solution for achieving this?

Comment: Hey Alexis, can you provide  a little bit of code please :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When "element" occurs, add an overriding class to the ball that sends it back to the original location in whatever fashion you desire.  If your return animation requires the current location of the ball, then calculate the location in javascript and provide the data to CSS directly in js or via a css variable.

Comment: Just updated my question, thanks for your answers.
What I have now: when clicked, the ball finishes the animation (at the top or the bottom) and the class is removed. The problem is that when it finishes at the top, it "jumps" to the bottom when the class is removed. I would like to pause the animation (immediately) and smoothly bring the ball to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getComputedStyle()`. In jQuery, you can do it through `.css()`.

> The .css() method is a convenient way to get a style property from the
>   first matched element, especially in light of the different ways
>   browsers access most of those properties (the getComputedStyle()
>   method in standards-based browsers versus the currentStyle and
>   runtimeStyle properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms
>   browsers use for certain properties.

For **CSS**, let's modify it a little bit. Make the default behaviour to be paused (`animation-play-state: paused`) and for `.loading`, set it to run. The paused moment is when you get the computed style to deal with it.

In **jQuery**, the animation will be paused, then the CSS transform (that is a `matrix()`) will be stored and applied to the element, next to a transition and the animation that will be set to `none` Finally, after some delay, it will run a function to apply a transform in order to bring the element back to the starting position.

```js
jQuery( ".button" ).click(function() {

    $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('loading');
    computedTransform = $this.css("transform");

    $this.css({"transform": computedTransform, "transition": "0.86s", "animation": "none"}).delay(20).queue(function() { 
        $this.css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)")
  });

});
```

```css
.button{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50vh - 10px);
    left: calc(50vw - 10px);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: bouncing 1s ease infinite alternate forwards paused;
}

.loading {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes bouncing{
    from {transform: translateY(0);}
    to {transform: translateY(-100px);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button loading"></div>
```